# Log (count) network

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, logging

Using Windows 7, how can I log the amount of GB I use? I only want to count from my own client computer and NOT COUNT a specific program/port.

Does something like this exists? I have a limit of 100GB/month (free inside a certain radius) and I want to count how much I use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found http://www.desksoft.com/BWMeter_Download.htm that works just like I want it with option to block specific ports or programs to log.

Comment: @Philia: Yeah, after two days...

Answer (score 0):

For a lightweight solution, tou can use [AnalogX](http://www.analogx.com/contents/download/network/nsl.htm), as described in [this article](http://www.simplehelp.net/2007/09/09/how-to-monitor-your-internet-bandwidth-usage-in-windows/). AnalogX is a network monitor, but if you set it to start on logon (and disable other monitoring you don't need), it can keep track of your total bandwidth usage.

Another tool is [PRTG Network Monitor](http://www.paessler.com/prtg/), which is meant for IT departments but is freeware for personal use. It runs all the time and can provide a number of reports on your usage.

Comment: I couldnt see neither of those program having the option to block specific port or programs. I found myself a program. See my answer.